# Material UI examples, ReferenceError: Element is not defined

Tags: material-ui

I broke one of my next js projects Tried do deploy ssr and next js examples from material ui github repo to codesandbox, same error on both examples.

Downgrading @material-ui/core version 4.9.10 seems to fix the error in the examples. But not in my project, clues where to begin?

[Link to Material Ui examples](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples)

```
[ error ] ReferenceError: Element is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/nextjs/node_modules/@material-ui/core/node_modules/react-transition-group/cjs/Transition.js:452:44)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/nextjs/node_modules/@material-ui/core/node_modules/react-transition-group/cjs/CSSTransition.js:14:42)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/nextjs/node_modules/@material-ui/core/node_modules/react-transition-group/cjs/index.js:6:45)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
```

Update: 
react-transition-group released version 4.4.1 a few minutes ago. Fixes the issue.

Comment: , I had the same issue, To fix it  , i deleted my yarn.lock , `rm -rf nodes_modules` and run `yarn`